# Problem adding a smart contract into a Substrate node

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template, substrate-contracts-node

I added these pallets into `runtime Cargo.toml` :

```
pallet-contracts = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git",  " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git",  " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
```

And added this codes into the `lib.rs`:

```rs
construct_runtime!(
    pub struct Runtime
    where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        DEX: pallet_dex,
        Contracts: pallet_contracts,

    }
);
```

config :

```rs
parameter_types! {
    pub const DepositPerItem: Balance = deposit(1, 0);
    pub const DepositPerByte: Balance = deposit(0, 1);
    pub const DeletionQueueDepth: u32 = 128;
    pub DeletionWeightLimit: Weight = AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO * BlockWeights::get().max_block;
    pub Schedule: pallet_contracts::Schedule<Runtime> = Default::default();
  }

impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Time = Timestamp;
    type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type CallFilter = Nothing;
    type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Self>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type ChainExtension = ();
    type Schedule = Schedule;
    type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 31];
    type DeletionQueueDepth = DeletionQueueDepth;
    type DeletionWeightLimit = DeletionWeightLimit;
    type DepositPerByte = DepositPerByte;
    type DepositPerItem = DepositPerItem;
    type AddressGenerator = pallet_contracts::DefaultAddressGenerator;
    type MaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 256 * 1024 }>;
    type MaxDebugBufferLen = ConstU32<{ 256 * 1024 }>;

    type MaxStorageKeyLen = ConstU32<{ 512 * 1024 }>;
    type UnsafeUnstableInterface = ConstBool<true>;
}
```

In the next step I want to upload a smart contract in this enviroment :

https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/instantiate

[image]

**** But the next button isn't active, and also I can't find the contract address.

**What's the problem? How can I solve this problem???**

Comment: Can you share your repo link here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like is an issue with the version. See the alert from the [Substrate Contracts UI repository](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui):

> ❗Only compatible with nodes that use WeightV2. For older nodes use this deployment❗

Try to deploy the smart contract in using this link: https://weightv1--contracts-ui.netlify.app/

Or try to update your node using the last version of Polkadot.
For testing you can try to run the last version of [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) and see if your contract can be deployed here.

Comment: thanks for answer but i want to use my substrate node , not using the substrate-contract-node .

Comment: Yes, it was just to test. With your node as I said in the response try to upload your contract in  https://weightv1--contracts-ui.netlify.app/ or update the version of your node.

Comment: man sorry for this but i still dont undrestand . let me explain my project . i want to implement `dex` in substrate . user can upload them smart contract and add that contract address into the my dex . know if i use ` substrate-contracts-node` for upload the smart contract , can i access to that smart contract for transfer token or any thing in my substrate node or not ?

Comment: Your issue here is that the next button isn't active, so you can not deploy the smart contract, isn't it? Try to upload using the link I mention before instead of the  https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/