# Error when implementing contract-pallet into substrate-node-template

Tags: substrate-node-template, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

I was looking to implement smart-contract into substrate-node-template as I do not want to use substrate-contracts-node.
I was trying to follow this guide - https://substrate-developer-hub.github.io/substrate-how-to-guides/docs/pallet-design/add-contracts-pallet/

However, I went into this error the moment I've insert the dependencies and tried `cargo build`.

```
# Contracts specific packages
pallet-contracts = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", package = "pallet-contracts", default-features = false, branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", package = "pallet-contracts-primitives", default-features = false, branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
```

There are a total of 11 errors and these are two of most common ones.

```
error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/<name>/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3bb3882/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs:549:6
    |
549 |                     vec![T::Hashing::hash_of(&dest), code_hash, contract.code_hash],

error: cannot find macro `thread_local` in this scope
   --> /home/<name>/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3bb3882/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs:975:3
    |
975 |         environmental!(executing_contract: bool);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My current setup is vanilla, cloned from - https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template

This is my current rustc version

```
rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.71.0-nightly (74c482104 2023-05-04)`
```

Things I tried to do:

- Changing the toolchain version to nightly-2023-01-01-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
- Tried to follow this: [Problem adding a smart contract into a Substrate node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7031/problem-adding-a-smart-contract-into-a-substrate-node)
- Clean install

Side note: is there any updated tutorial on implementing smart contract into substrate node template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good basic tutorial on adding a pallet (I am sure you are aware of it):

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-a-pallet

Generally speaking, whenever I want to add a pallet, I refer to the "kitchensink" runtime, as it has a conglomerate of pallets already configured:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a87e56f1696cae44593cdc069a01d8bed0bab636/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1808

I also put together a repo for you. It is the substrate-node-template with pallet contracts. You can follow the commits to see how I added it.

- https://github.com/brunopgalvao/substrate-contracts-template

Keep in mind this is for demo purposes and the you may want to change the contracts pallet config to your liking.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the repo. It is a lifesaver. I do have a question in mind. Why do substrate add 'runtime' to certain variables? 

For example, in substrate repo, it uses [RuntimeBlockWeights](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a87e56f1696cae44593cdc069a01d8bed0bab636/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L220).

Whereas, in your repo, you used [BlockWeights](https://github.com/brunopgalvao/substrate-contracts-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L158).

Comment: This is a very good question. Created another post for this: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/what-is-the-difference-between-runtimeblockweights-vs-blockweights