# What is the difference between `RuntimeBlockWeights` vs `BlockWeights`?

Tags: weight, block

I notice that in the node-template there is `BlockWeights` and some differences in weights compared to the `"kitchensink"` runtime where we have `RuntimeBlockWeights`.

What is the difference between `BlockWeights` and `RuntimeBlockWeights`? Is there a reason why both runtimes are not the same?

```rust
const NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(75);

parameter_types! {
    pub const BlockHashCount: BlockNumber = 2400;
    pub const Version: RuntimeVersion = VERSION;
    /// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block time.
    pub BlockWeights: frame_system::limits::BlockWeights =
        frame_system::limits::BlockWeights::with_sensible_defaults(
            Weight::from_parts(2u64 * WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND, u64::MAX),
            NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO,
        );
    pub BlockLength: frame_system::limits::BlockLength = frame_system::limits::BlockLength
        ::max_with_normal_ratio(5 * 1024 * 1024, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
    pub const SS58Prefix: u8 = 42;
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2fc9c39a9fb9f38b6256f82cda4c955eb0de2706/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#LL136C1-L150C2

```rust
/// We assume that ~10% of the block weight is consumed by `on_initialize` handlers.
/// This is used to limit the maximal weight of a single extrinsic.
const AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(10);
/// We allow `Normal` extrinsics to fill up the block up to 75%, the rest can be used
/// by  Operational  extrinsics.
const NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(75);
/// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block time, with maximum proof size.
const MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT: Weight =
    Weight::from_parts(WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND.saturating_mul(2), u64::MAX);

parameter_types! {
    pub const BlockHashCount: BlockNumber = 2400;
    pub const Version: RuntimeVersion = VERSION;
    pub RuntimeBlockLength: BlockLength =
        BlockLength::max_with_normal_ratio(5 * 1024 * 1024, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
    pub RuntimeBlockWeights: BlockWeights = BlockWeights::builder()
        .base_block(BlockExecutionWeight::get())
        .for_class(DispatchClass::all(), |weights| {
            weights.base_extrinsic = ExtrinsicBaseWeight::get();
        })
        .for_class(DispatchClass::Normal, |weights| {
            weights.max_total = Some(NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO * MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT);
        })
        .for_class(DispatchClass::Operational, |weights| {
            weights.max_total = Some(MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT);
            // Operational transactions have some extra reserved space, so that they
            // are included even if block reached `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT`.
            weights.reserved = Some(
                MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT - NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO * MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT
            );
        })
        .avg_block_initialization(AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO)
        .build_or_panic();
    pub MaxCollectivesProposalWeight: Weight = Perbill::from_percent(50) * RuntimeBlockWeights::get().max_block;
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2fc9c39a9fb9f38b6256f82cda4c955eb0de2706/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L180-L214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the naming and how complicated they are set up.
The template runtime is always kept simple to have a minimal working example. The kitchensink on the other hand tries to use most features, and acts like a "fat" runtime that is closer to how a real chain would be configured.